# request.pipe() allow failing request

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, request

I am forwarding my enriched request using `request.pipe()`.
Problem is that it forwards the response when the piped request is successful but it responds with an error when the request fails. What I want is for the pipe to respond with whatever the request is returning. For example when it returns a 404 then pass along the 404 response to the original request.

Here's what I have

```
app.all('*', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  req.headers.extraHeader = JSON.stringify(res.locals.infoFromMiddleware)

  req.pipe(request(`http://localhost:3000${req.url}`)).pipe(res)
})
```

I get the following error:
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 404` (or 400 / 500 / etc.)

Comment: What error do you get ? It might have something to do with the fact that express calls your error middleware  before this method which means a response is sent back before piping it to the proxy.

Comment: I updated the questtion

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this

```
app.all('*', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  req.headers.extraHeader = JSON.stringify(res.locals.infoFromMiddleware)

  req
   .pipe(request(`http://localhost:3000${req.url}`))
   .once('error', err => res.status(404).send(JSON.stringify(err)))
   .pipe(res)
})
```

Comment: but it's not just about handling the 404. I want the proxy the pass along the response regardless of the error and also include the response body and headers.